# Long Waiting Times on GoDaddy?

Tags: optimization, performance

I prefer not to use GoDaddy because I always encounter performance issues. However, one of my clients is rather insistent on using them... so we are.

I've tested this with a vanilla Wordpress 3.0+ install with no active plugins, but it always seems to happen for me: Whenever a new page/post is called by the browser, we encounter 3-10 second "waiting" times.

[image]

I don't have this problem on any non-godaddy wordpress installs (they nearly always get their pages in queue in under 2 seconds). But all my Godaddy installs exhibit this behavior.

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: Are you caching? Using W3TC, Super Cache, or WP-Cache, and others?

Comment: Just to add: loading times are fine once the page is actually loading.

Comment: Yes, using W3TC

Comment: From personal experience time to first byte is near-impossible to diagnose or improve on shared hosting. It's up to hosting support.

Comment: In regards to W3TC, PHP Sessions will disable page caching.  Make sure you are page caching, check the debug info.

Comment: I do think it's GoDaddy's fault, but our CakePHP site, unlike WP, is only dealing with 400ms-1.4 second wait times... no clue why.

Comment: I have the same issue with goDaddy shared...

Can anybody suggest a more reliable (shared, cheap) hosting company?

Comment: I have the same issue with another hosting company and I'm not even using Wordpress. I recommend using a Virtual Private Server instead, even though I understand that is probably not an option for the OP.

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**: *generic server configuration and administration* are explicitly out of our scope.

Answer (score 8):

It's really simply GoDaddy and slow mysql and webservers. I've heard apocryphal stories of people making lots of noise to GoDaddy support and as a result, speeds improve. Do they get moved to better servers or get priority load-balancing? Impossible to say.

One other thing to try is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/use-google-libraries/  but sometimes it doesn't help much with an overall slow shared hosting system.

Answer (score 5):

> I prefer not to use GoDaddy because I
>   always encounter performance issues.
>   However, one of my clients is rather
>   insistent on using them... so we are.

This is exactly what I do in reverse , I insist that if they want to stay with godaddy they can find another developer/designer.

Comment: Haha.. totally! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Godaddy is to blame. I think a monkey does everything manually whenever we submit a request for anything. Be it a password change or anything, it will take several minutes before anything happens. Monkey is so busy dealing with everything.

Other than that they throttle their FTP connections, limit number of concurrent FTP connections, always have permission issues & are terrible in performance.

And lets not forget there servers are poorly configured which leads to hacked sites and several times, WP is blamed for getting hacked.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using godaddy, I had the same problem with them.

You are referring to [TTFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_To_First_Byte), (Time to first Byte).
Regular TTFB range from 0.3 to 1.5 sec max. in a good server configuration.

It doesn't matter if you use [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), Minimize your java/css. 
Although your website after the TTFB load fine,  If the server is not well configured/optimized it will take too much time to deliver the first byte.

The use of [cache plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/), CDN and improved code will only affect how your website load after the TTFB.

An excellent tool for test is http://www.webpagetest.org/

My suggestion, Find another web host, preferable close to your client location if visitors are locals.

Answer (score 1):

GoDaddy make use CloudLinux on their servers, meaning you're allocated a small amount of CPU, RAM and a certain number of concurrent connections to Apache per user.

CloudLinux makes it possible for GoDaddy to indeed "prioritise" users based on the noise they make to tech-support by simply allocating a larger portion of the CPU/RAM available for bursting to.

CloudLinux however is a good thing when reasonable limits are set, as it means abusive users cannot consume 95% of the servers total processing power and RAM, but when limited too harshly will indeed result in the experience you're having.

I implore you to go forth and whine at tech-support to increase your limits :-)

Answer (score 0):

I too, use Godaddy for all my sites and web hosting, but for some reason the php/mySQL specific sites (wordpress etc..) were taking, on average, 8-20 seconds to start loading the page which was no acceptable. I did the normal troubleshooting, disable all plug-ins etc.. but nothing helped. 
Finally found the solution to this problem and may be a solution for others, not just GoDaddy. I was using a Windows Hosting account and switched to a Linux hosting account which is native to php/mySQL pages and now my site loads in less then 1-2 seconds.  Check out the fast load times yourself on my wordpress site http://techcentral.northwoodswebdesigns.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Godaddy WP hosting (not the basic one). The average waiting time when a new page or post is visited is around 6-12 seconds, especially in the mobile devices. Can anyone give some suggestions on my site, https://labellecosmetic.ca/ ? I don't know how to transfer to another server, so just looking for the solution on Godaddy itself.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/246497)